# XCode Indexing memory leak

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have strange issue in XCode 11. When XCode initially indexing my iOS project after deleting the DeriveData, in Activity Monitor I can see the some Swift processes, each of which consumes Gigabytes of RAM per every few seconds. After no longer than minute the MacOS goes into a state completely unusable. Any suggestions?

Comment: Happens to me too, every so often.